# How can I make template for WPF properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, properties

On my WPF XAML form I've got a lot of elements which I bind to my properties.

For each one property I'm making this steps:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="TB11" Text="{Binding TBX11}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

and

```
#region TBX11
private static void OnXBPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    table myUserControl = dependencyObject as table;
    myUserControl.OnPropertyChanged("XB11");
    myUserControl.OnCaptionPropertyChanged(e);
}
private void OnCaptionPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    TB11.Text = TBX11;
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TBX11Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TBX11", typeof(string), typeof(table),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnXBPropertyChanged));
public string TBX11 {
    get { return GetValue(TBX11Property).ToString(); }
    set {
        SetValue(TBX11Property, value);
        OnPropertyChanged("TBX11");
    }
}
#endregion
```

I can't even realize for now how many times I will need to write the same here but I don't know if I can make it somehow easier? Because all I need to set from here is WPF block name and binding name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can reduce repetition:

1. Introduce user-controls for reducing repeated XAML and C# code. See [this tutorial I wrote](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/) for more details.
2. If you have a list of identical UI elements, as an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate` to create the repeated elements.

I have spotted a few issues with your code:

1. In your `OnCaptionPropertyChanged` method you set the `TextBlock.Text`, you should noty do this - this binding will take care of the update!
2. Within your `TBX11` property you invoke this method `OnPropertyChanged("TBX11")`, you should not add any logic to the getters or setters of dependency properties. There is no guarantee these will be invoked.
3. Your `TextBlock.DataContext` is set to itself, so the `Text` binding will not work!

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if I can make it somehow easier?

You can use MVVM framework like [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/).

Caliburn will allow you to rewrite your XAML as

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="TB11"  
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: I really would not recommend adding a dependency to a complex MVVM framework just to remove a bit of repetition. The WPF framework itself can solve this problem.